# Can I bind asp.net razor select list as an array to a model property after posting the form?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, drop-down-menu

I am binding List collection to asp.net mvc select tag. Is there a way after posting the page to get the select items as an model list array? In my case binded model list collection  is null after submit the form.

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FruitViewModel fruitViewModel = new FruitViewModel();
            fruitViewModel.FruitLists = FruitService.PopulateFruits();
            return View(fruitViewModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(FruitViewModel fruitViewModel)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Fruit Name: " + fruitViewModel.FruitName;
            ViewBag.Message += "\\nFruit Id: " + fruitViewModel.FruitId;
            return View(fruitViewModel);
        }
/////////////////////////////////
@model Models.FruitViewModel

<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <select id="ddlFruits" name="@Model.FruitId" asp-items="Model.FruitLists">
        <option value="0">Please select</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="FruitName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I am not sure if you want to select one option then bind it to an array property or you want to select multi options and bind them to an array property, I write two simple demos to implement these two scenarios.

Model

```
public class FruitViewModel
        {
            public int[] FruitId { get; set; }
        }
```

Get method

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> selectlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "1",Value = "1"});
            selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
            selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
            selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "4", Value = "4" });
            selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
            ViewBag.data = selectlist;
            return View();
        }
```

**The first one is selecting one option and bind it to an array property.**

View

```
@model FruitViewModel

<form method="post">
    <select name="FruitId[0]" asp-items="@ViewBag.data">
        <option>Please select</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]

**The second demo is selecting multi options to bind an array property.**

view

```
@model FruitViewModel

<form method="post">
    <select name="FruitId" asp-items="@ViewBag.data" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Please select</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]